# Delegates and Callbacks

Tags: c#, callback

Does the term callback in the context of delegates mean ,"*a delegate delegating it works to another delegate inorder to finish some task*" ?

Example :(***Based on my understanding,I have implemented a callback,correct me if it is wrong***)

```
namespace Test
{
    public delegate string CallbackDemo(string str);  

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallbackDemo handler = new CallbackDemo(StrAnother);
            string substr = Strfunc(handler);
            Console.WriteLine(substr);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static string Strfunc(CallbackDemo callback)
        {
           return callback("Hello World");   
        }

        static string StrAnother(string str)
        {
            return str.Substring(1, 3).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide examples as necessary.

Comment: imho valuable to think of a Delegate as a Type that is a function pointer to a Method : like an Interface or a Class : it's a template for an instance which is itself a reference to its internal Method : the instance can be passed around between objects and invoked/executed at any time.

If you have any way to get hold of "C# in Depth," by Jon Skeet, and read the chapter 2 section on Delegates, and Chapter 5 on Delegates, imho you will understand the "evolution" of delegates from their "larval stage" in C# 1.0, to their fully "evolved" form in C# 3.0. I've never found a better exposition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example is a good start, but it is incorrect. You don't make a new delegate in the method, it's used in the declaration of an event in the class. See this modified example of your code:

```
namespace Test
{
    //In this case, this delegate declaration is like specifying a specific kind of function that must be used with events.
    public delegate string CallbackDemo(string str);
    class Program
    {
        public static event CallbackDemo OnFoobared;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this means that StrAnother is "subscribing" to the event, in other words it gets called when the event is fired
            OnFoobared += StrAnother;
            string substr = Strfunc();
            Console.WriteLine(substr);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            //this is the other use of delegates, in this case they are being used as an "anonymous function". 
            //This one takes no parameters and returns void, and it's equivalent to the function declaration 
            //'void myMethod() { Console.WriteLine("another use of a delegate"); }'
            Action myCode = delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("another use of a delegate");
            };
            myCode();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            //the previous 4 lines are equivalent to the following however this is generally what you should use if you can
            //its called a lambda expression but it's basically a way to toss arbitrary code around
            //read more at http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3598381/The-New-Lambda-Expressions-Feature-in-C-30.htm or 
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this
            Action myCode2 = () => Console.WriteLine("a lambda expression");
            myCode2();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static string Strfunc()
        {
            return OnFoobared("a use of a delegate (with an event)");
        }
        static string StrAnother(string str)
        {
            return str.Substring(1, 3).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I've only scratched the surface here; search stack overflow for "delegate c#" and "lambda expression c#" for lots more!

Answer (score 4):

A callback is what the delegate executes when it is invoked. For example, when using the Asynchronous pattern using delegates, you would do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket s = new Socket(...);
    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    s.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 10, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnMessageReceived), buffer);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void OnMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // ...
}
```

`OnMessageReceived` is the callback, the code that is executed by invoking the delegate. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) for some more information, or Google some more examples.

Answer (score 3):

A callback is basically a delegate passed into a procedure which that procedure will "call back" at some appropriate point.  For example, in asynchronous calls such as WebRequest.BeginGetResponse or a WCF BeginXxx operation, you'd pass an AsyncCallback.  The worker will "call back" whatever method you pass in as the AsyncCallback, in this case when it's finished to let you know that it's finished and to obtain the result.

An event handler could be considered another example.  For example, when you attach a handler to a Click event, the button will "call back" to that handler when the click occurs.

Answer (score 3):

This will get down voted precisely for the reason it is correct. C# does not implement delegates, what it implements is call forwarding. This incorrect use of nomenclature is probably the biggest problem with C# in this regard.

The ACM paper below is the first description of what later would be called a delegate. Basically a delegate is something that appears to be an instance of an object (how it is actually implemented is irrelevant). This means that you can call methods, access properties, etc. from the delegate.

http://web.media.mit.edu/~lieber/Lieberary/OOP/Delegation/Delegation.html

What C# implements is callbacks or call-forwarding (all dependent on how you use them). These are not delegates. In order to be a delegate one be able to access the object as if it were the object itself.

> When a pen delegates a draw message to a prototypical pen, it is saying “I don’t know how to handle the draw message. I’d like you to answer it for me if you can, but if you have any further questions, like what is the value of my x variable, or need anything done, you should come back to me and ask.” If the message is delegated further, all questions about the values of variables or requests to reply to messages are all inferred to the object that delegated the message in the first place. - Henry Lieberman

So, how did it get messed up? To be honest, I don't know. I DO know that I've been using delegates (over 16 years now) long before C# and what C# implements are not delegates.

A really good explanation can be had here.

http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2012/07/06/the-gang-of-four-is-wrong-and-you-dont-understand-delegation/

Real delegation is more than creating callbacks or call forwarding. A real delegate lets me call any method on that object, get and/or set public properties, etc - all as if it was the object itself. This is far more powerful, and actually easier to use, than the C# "delegation".

The OP asked:

> Does the term callback in the context of delegates mean ,"a delegate delegating it works to another delegate inorder to finish some task" ?

The answer to this is yes. A callback in the context of delegates can **can only be** used to finish up some task. For example, you have a class that get's data from a weather site. Since it is non-deterministic, implementing a callback when the data has been received (and perhaps parsed) would be spiffy.

As to why delegation was corrupted, I've no idea. I look forward to C# implementing TRUE delegation.

Comment: Thank you. The naming has always confused me and now I understand exactly why.

Comment: When you actually DO use delegates the difference between what C# (and, sadly, others) call “delegates” is obvious: they are NOT implementing delegates at all. Delegates are easy and not at ALL confusing. I’m currently dealing with an API that uses what it “thinks” are “delegates” but are really callbacks and call-forwarding. <sigh>