# Want to know how to pass a function as an argument in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to pass a function as an argument just like this:

```
void AvoidSpawn(float sRate, function f) 
    {
        float calculateRate = 0;
        if(Time.time>=calculateRate)
        {
            f();
            calculateRate = Time.time + spawnRate;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to use a function as an argument and pass it and I would like to replace `function f` with something that works.

Comment: Read about [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). Then read about [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-7.0) and [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Or read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-7.0

Comment: Duplicate of: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3622160/13927459) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2082615/13927459) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function that doesn't return any value (a `void` method), there are various [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) delegates.

For a function that *does* return a value, you need [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1) and friends.

There are various versions to account for a number of parameters (up to 16, nowadays).

So you can define your function as

```
void AvoidSpawn(float sRate, Action f) 
{
   // ...
   f();
   // ...
}
```

And either call it with a lambda:

```
AvoidSpawn(1.0f, () => Console.WriteLine("Avoiding spawn"));
```

or mention another method

```
AvoidSpawn(1.0f, SomeVoidMethod);
```

Note: do not use `()` there, you don't want to *call* that method yet.

Comment: The duplicate question also has a lot of info