# C# Passing a method as a parameter to another method

Tags: c#, methods

I have a method that is called when an exception occurs:

```
public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must refresh the datasource");
}
```

What i would like to do is pass this function a method so if the user clicks Yes then the method is called e.g.

```
public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e, something Method)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("You must refresh the datasource") == DialogResult.OK)
        Method();
}
```

The Method may or may not have parameters, if this is the case i would like to pass them too.

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate type.

```
public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e, Action method)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("You must refresh the datasource") == DialogResult.OK)
        method();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void MyAction()
{

}

ErrorDBConcurrency(e, MyAction);
```

If you do need parameters you can use a lambda expression.

```
ErrorDBConcurrency(e, () => MyAction(1, 2, "Test"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Add an `Action` as parameter:

```
public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e, Action errorAction)
{
   if (MessageBox.Show("You must refresh the datasource") == DialogResult.OK)
       errorAction()
}
```

and then you can call it like this

```
ErrorDBConcurrency(ex, () => { do_something(foo); });
```

or

```
ErrorDBConcurrency(ex, () => { do_something_else(bar, baz); });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as the parameter type.

If `Method` returns `void`, then `something` is [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx), `Action<T1>`, `Action<T1, T2>`, etc (where T1...Tn are the parameter types for `Method`).

If `Method` returns a value of type `TR`, then `something` is [`Func<TR>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx), `Func<T1, TR>`, `Func<T1, T2, TR>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Func and Action classes. You can achieve this using the following:

```
public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e, Action method)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("You must refresh the datasource") == DialogResult.OK)
        method()
}

public void Method()
{
    // do stuff
}
//....
```

Call it using

```
ErrorDBConcurrency(ex, Method)
```

Take a look at [this article](http://dotnetkicks.com/linq/Action_Func_Predicate_what_s_going_on) for some details. If you want your method to take a parameter, use Action, Action, etc. If you want it to return a value, use Func etc. There are many overloads of these generic classes.

Comment: That should just be `ErrorDBConcurrency(ex, Method)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public delegate void MethodHandler(); // The type

public void ErrorDBConcurrency(DBConcurrencyException e, MethodHandler Method) // Your error function

ErrorDBConcurrency (e, new MethodHandler(myMethod)); // Passing the method
```