# selenium wait until method returns true

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know that selenium webdriver can do that:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName("someclass")));
```

can't I do that on my method? For example I have a method which takes a screenshot and compares with another picture. I want to wait until that method returns true.

So I have this code

```
while (WelcomeScreen(driver) != true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);   
}
```

Can't I find any better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the **FluentWait**, I am not good with C# so following code example is in Java. if you can convert it to C#, I think it might work.

```
 Wait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

 wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return WelcomeScreen(driver)
                }
              }
 );
```

Comment: thanks for answer. equivalent in c# will be this code:

wait.Until((x) =>
            {
                if(WelcomeScreen(driver))
                    return true;

                return false;
            });

Comment: Is it possible to pass the method (in this case `public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return WelcomeScreen(driver)
                }` as a parameter?

Comment: @HappyBird what do you mean by passing the method, it returns the value returned by `WelcomeScreen` method.

Comment: The code you have posted, I like this. I want to put it in a method "WaitUntilTrue" and to this method, I want to pass "Welcomescreen(driver)". I think I already found the answer by using an Action delegate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414515/c-sharp-passing-a-method-as-a-parameter-to-another-method)