# C# referencing methods through variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, variables, methods

Lets say i have a method

```
public static void Blah(object MyMethod) { // i dont know what to replace object with
MyMethod; // or however you would use the variable
}
```

so basically i need to be able to reference a method through a variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [a delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

```
public delegate void SomeMethodDelegate();

public void DoSomething()
{
    // Do something special
}

public void UseDoSomething(SomeMethodDelegate d)
{
    d();
}
```

Usage:

```
UseDoSomething(DoSomething);
```

Or using lambda syntax (if `DoSomething` was a Hello World):

```
UseDoSomething(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
```

---

There is also shortcut syntax available for Delegates in the form of [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) types:

```
public void UseDoSomething(Action d)
```

And if you need to return a value from your delegate(like an `int` in my example) you can use:

```
public void UseDoSomething2(Func<int> d)
```

*NOTE:* [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) provide generic overloads that allow parameters to be passed.

Answer (score 4):

The .Net framework has a bunch of delegate types built-in which make this easier.  So if `MyMethod` takes a `string` parameter you could do this:

```
public static void Blah(Action<string> MyMethod) { 
    MyMethod; 
}
```

if it takes two `int`s and returns a `long` you would do:

```
public static void Blah(Func<int, int, long> MyMethod) { 
    MyMethod; 
}
```

There are versions of `Action<>` and `Func<>` with varying number of type parameters which you can specify as required.