# Reusable Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, parameter-passing

I'm been wanting to create a user control, but before I do I need to know how to do a few things or even if its possible.  I know it possible to pass a method to a function ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)).  Is it possible to set a variable that is of function type?  For example I have a user control where in one function I need to call GetData function. Each GetData routine is different so I was wondering if its possible to pass that function in from the aspx.cs page?

Comment: Your question is very broad and vague. I'm guessing the terms you're looking for are "delegate" and "event handler". Consider reading up on these then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I will look into that. If I can pass a function into a private variable in a user control.  Then I would be good.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework Library defines handy generic delegates (or "function types" as you call it). Function delegates that have a return value

```
Func<Ret>
Func<Arg, Ret>
Func<Arg1, Arg2, Ret>
...
```

Function delegates that have no return value

```
Action<>
Action<Arg>
Action<Arg1, Arg2>
...
```

You can define a method that accepts a delegate like this

```
void DrawFunction(Func<double, double> function, double x0, double x1)
{
    const double step = 0.1;

    for (x = x0; x <= x1; x += step) {
        double y = function(x);
        DrawPointAt(x, y);
    }
}
```

---

You can call it by either passing it an appropriate method or with a lambda expression.

Using this declaration

```
public double Square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

You can do the call (note that the parentheses () are missing after `Square` since we do not want to call this method here)

```
DrawFunction(Square, 0.0, 10.0);
```

You get the same result with a lambda expression

```
DrawFunction(x => x*x, 0.0, 10.0);
```