# Pass Method of Unknown Arguments/Return Type as Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions, methodinfo

There's a similar question here:

[Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Which assumes you know the method's arguments and return type. I'd like to do something a bit different. I'm looking to create a version of System.Reflection's .GetMethod(string) that instead takes a lambda function - so instead of:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("AddThing");
```

I could use a more compile-safe:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = ReflectionHelper.GetMethod<MyClass>(mc => mc.AddThing);
```

So if ReflectionHelper knew the argument count and return type beforehand the answer would be simple-ish - for example if it had no arguments and returned string:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, Func<TArg, TReturn>>> expr)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method;
}
```

Except that I don't know the argument count/return type beforehand, and I'd like to avoid just spamming it with 20 overloads that cover most but not all cases.

So, how do I do this?

Comment: If you don't know the arguments it accepts what do you plan to pass into the method to try to call it?

Comment: @Johnny5 I don't see how.  That would still require a fixed signature when it's called, or at least a signature that complies with the arguments supplied.

Comment: @Servy The ReflectionHelper doesn't know the arguments it accepts, but the calling method very likely does. Can't answer with clean code in comments but basically ReflectionHelper.GetMethod<MyClass>(mc => mc.MyMethod).Invoke("Hi"); // We know there's only one argument to MyMethod here where we're calling GetMethod, but GetMethod itself is more flexible and could be used in a variety of situations where it doesn't know the structure of the methods it will be used on.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified a method in the lambda `mc => mc.AddThing` - you've specified a method group.

What you could do is write a method call in the expression - although it will never be executed, so the parameters just have to specify the overload you want.

So, to use it, you would write:

```
MethodInfo mi = GetMethod<MyClass>( mc => mc.AddThing( null ) );
```

Then the expression could just be an `Action`, not a `Func`:

```
public static MethodInfo<T>( Expression<Action<T>> expr )
{
  return ( ( MethodCallExpression ) x.Body ).Method;
}
```

As always with expression inspection, this is prone to runtime errors if the lambda isn't of the expected form, but it's a step in the right direction to get rid of "magic" strings.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction - I dislike passing the fake arguments in order to specify the method, although it would be somewhat simpler to type given it would involve more help from the IDE than the similar answer I posted below. Unfortunately neither answer gets me to my goal, however.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I'm using for now, that I'll call "the spam approach," is ugly but functional in a limited set of scenarios:

```
public class ReflectionHelper<T>
{
    public MethodInfo GetMethod<TA1>(Expression<Func<T, Func<TA1>>> expr)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method;
    }
    public MethodInfo GetMethod<TA1, TA2>(Expression<Func<T, Action<TA1, TA2>>> expr)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method;
    }
    public MethodInfo GetMethod<TA1, TA2, TA3>(Expression<Func<T, Action<TA1, TA2, TA3>>> expr)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method;
    }
    . . . // And more
}
```

And it goes on, to specify a long list of potential Actions and Funcs with various argument counts. This allows me to in fact use it like:

```
(new ReflectionHelper<MyClass>()).GetMethod<string>(mc => mc.SaySomething).Invoke("Hi");
```

So it's close-ish - I get to just call the method by name, and I do avoid passing fake arguments in order to do so, but I still get caught up laying out what the Types of its arguments are - more complex than I hoped for. In a situation with multiple method overloads of the same name, passing the types of the arguments would however narrow the method list down to one specific overload.

I'd still be interested in something even simpler that can just take a method as in my Question however. It would be vague in method overload situations, but so is the standard .GetMethod(string).