# Returning a method from a C# method

Tags: c#, methods, return-value, return-type

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp) that explains how to pass methods as parameters in C#.

What I need to know is how to return a method as the result of another method invocation.

```
method = DoSomething()
result = method()
```

Comment: Simply return a Func delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use either [**`Action<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) or [**`Func<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Like this:

```
private Action<string> Returns(string user)
{
    return () => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey {0}", user);
    };
}
```

or this:

```
private Func<bool> TestsIsThirty(int value)
{
    return () => value == 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you want your return type to be a `Delegate`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) delegates.

Answer (score 2):

```
var method =()=> DoSomething();
result = method();
```