# Passing method as parameter to another method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I am developing project in widows c#.net. In the form i have more than 8 combobox control. 
I will load data to combobox2 when combobox1 selection is changed like below.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     comboBox2.DataSource = DataTable;
     comboBox2.DisplayMember="Name";
     comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

Combobox3 will be loaded when i select combobox2 like below.

```
 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     comboBox3.DataSource = DataTable;
     comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Age";
     comboBox3.ValueMember = "AgeCode";
 }
```

Like i will load data to the rest of combobox.
The problem here is error will occur, if i did not check in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method whether comboBox2 is loaded or not.

I know we can check this by using Boolean variable, but horrible thing is we need to maintain its "true/false" state for rest all  methods.

so what I have thought to fix this in simple way is that, I will use `Add(combobox, Methodname)` method and `Remove(combobox, method)` methods to add and remove the `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` function from combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

But I couldn't pass the method as parameter. Can anybody tell me that how to pass method as parameter for my requirement.

Comment: take a look at `Func` and `Action`

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082650/182344

Comment: You can pass delegates as parameters. But I don't think this will solve your problem.

Comment: @jeevacl By `method` parameter in `Add` and `Remove` method you meant `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` and/or `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` ?

Comment: `whether comboBox2 is loaded or not`. are you loading your combobox dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `method` parameter in `Add` and `Remove` method if you meant `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and/or `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` then solution is

```
private void Add(ListControl dropDownList, EventHandler handlerMethodName)
{
   dropDownList.OnSelectedIndexChanged += handlerMethodName;
   //some logic here
}

private void Remove(ListControl dropDownList, EventHandler handlerMethodName)
{
   dropDownList.OnSelectedIndexChanged -= handlerMethodName;
   //some logic here
}
```

Please note: It is `DropDownList` in `ASP.NET`, `ComboBox` is for `WinForms` applications.

For more refer: [MSDN - DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) and [MSDN - ListControl.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: @jeevacl I had answered before Alexander and He have gave same answer  as I have.. :( This is not fair game..

Comment: Hey friend, actually i would like to accept all others answers too. but i couldn't.... and i did not listen the first comment by you..... i just seen the answer only... sorry.... And i have lot of doubts in asp.net... if you give me your mail id i would be helpful to me.... mine is jeevacl@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are tryng to do. but why not a dictionary of ComboBox and methods?

like this:

```
var dict = Dictionary<ComboBox, Action<object, EventArgs>>();

private void Add(ComboBox c, Action<object, EventArgs>e) {
   dict[c] = e;
}

private void Remove(ComboBox c, Action<object, EventArgs> e) {
   dict.Remove(c);
}
```

And to call ::

```
private void CallHandler(ComboBox c, EventArgs e)
{
   dict[c](c, e);
}
```

---

Alternatively

```
private void AddHandler(ComboBox c, Action<object, EventArgs> e)
{
   c.SelectedIndexChanged += e;
}

private void RemoveHandler(ComboBox c, Action<object, EventArgs> e)
{
   c.SelectedIndexChanged -= e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks lol.... there is quite difficult to understand dictionary.. anyhow the alternative is helpful and got solution... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am also not 100% sure that kind of solution you are looking for, but my understanding of your need are the following methods:

```
public void Add(DropDownList combo, EventHandler method)
{
    combo.SelectedIndexChanged += method;
}

public void Remove(DropDownList combo, EventHandler method)
{
    combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= method;
}
```

Now you can define your own method that should have the same signature as `EventHandler` delegate:

```
public void MyMethod1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

And you can register and unregister your methods by calling the above defined methods:

```
DropDownList lst = new DropDownList();
Add(lst, MyMethod1);
Remove(lst, MyMethod1);
```

But beware, that this might be not an optimal solution of your problem.