# Passing a function as parameter

Tags: c#, methods

I need a way to define a method in c# like this:

```
public String myMethod(Function f1,Function f2)
{
    //code
}
```

Let f1 is:

```
public String f1(String s1, String s2)
{
    //code
}
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: [C# Delegates, Anonymous Methods, and Lambda Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Sure you can use the [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx) delegate:

```
public String myMethod(
    Func<string, string, string> f1,
    Func<string, string, string> f2)
{
    //code
}
```

This delegate defines a function which takes two string parameters and return a string. It has numerous cousins to define functions which take different numbers of parameters. To call `myMethod` with another method, you can simply pass in the name of the method, for example:

```
public String doSomething(String s1, String s2) { ... }
public String doSomethingElse(String s1, String s2) { ... }

public String myMethod(
    Func<string, string, string> f1,
    Func<string, string, string> f2)
{
    //code
    string result1 = f1("foo", "bar");
    string result2 = f2("bar", "baz");
    //code
}
...

myMethod(doSomething, doSomethingElse);
```

Of course, if the parameter and return types of `f2` aren't exactly the same, you may need to adjust the method signature accordingly.

Comment: In addition: when you want to execute the f1 and f2, you only need to call them as methods.   string result = f1("first", "second");

Comment: Is it mean that I must call them by name(Jeroen van Langen)?

Comment: @Babak.Abad I've provided an example for how to call `f1` or `f2` as functions.

Comment: I was looking for this answer around three days, thanks!

Comment: If your method returns void, use Action instead of Func (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-2?view=net-5.0)