# Pass method as Parameter using C# 2.x (not 3.x)

Tags: c#-2.0

It's 2013, and a major platform *cough*Unity3d*cough* is seemingly still partly stuck on 2.x (latest Unity is newer, but isn't production-quality yet for some features). It seems there's a lot of stuff that was missing from the language until 3.5 - e.g. Func and Action - so I'm trying to find a way to do this without using 3.x.

Here's a great, very neat solution for 3.x: [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

I tried Microsoft's site, but it's currently refusing to give out docs for anything earlier than 4.5 (was working a few weeks ago, but now their Javascript always errors out :( ).

...what's the equivalent in 2.x? Or is there no way of doing this (sad face) ?

---

OR: am I missing something obvious about using Func? I get compiler errors that it's an undefined symbol, and I'm using the same context as I found in all the different online resources / examples :(

Comment: Delegates basically. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to distinguish between [*language* versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) and *platform* versions... and likewise functionality. Currently you're mixing up various aspects.

`Func` and `Action` aren't part of the C# language at all - they're just delegate types which are part of the .NET framework. If you're using a version of the framework which doesn't include the delegate types you want, just declare your own. I'd suggest naming them *differently* to the .NET ones so that it won't matter if you then upgrade - there won't be any naming collisions. So:

```
public delegate void MyAction();
public delegate void MyAction<T>(T input);
... etc
```

Then once the relevant types are in place, you can use method group conversions as normal:

```
public void DoSomething(MyAction<string> action) { ... }

public void Foo(string text) { ... }

...

DoSomething(Foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use delegates! Here are some links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx