# method as a parameter of constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm writing a K-Nearest Neighbors classifier class. I would like to allow the client the ability to specify the distance function to be used.

Can the constructor of my `KNNClassifier` object take a method as a parameter? In Python I'm doing this as follows:

```
class KNNClassifier:

    def __init__(self, examples, membership, n_classes, distance_func):

        self.examples      = examples
        self.membership    = membership
        self.n_classes     = n_classes
        self.distance_func = distance_func

        self.m = len(self.membership)
        self.n = len(self.examples[0])`
```

Can this be done in C#? I'm new to C# and an elementary example would be appreciated.

Comment: See here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp

Comment: Absolutely, use a delegate as a parameter. the link above provides a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). Here's a simple example using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, int> _distanceFunc

    public MyClass(Func<T, T, int> distanceFunc)
    {
        this._distanceFunc = distanceFunc;
    }
}
```

This declares a [generic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), `MyClass`, that takes one generic type parameter, `T`, and has a single constructor that takes one parameter. That parameter is itself a function that accepts two parameters of type `T` and returns an `int`. Within `MyClass`, the delegate that `_distanceFunc` points to may be invoked with parentheses, just like any other function:

```
T instanceA = ...
T instanceB = ...
int result = this._distanceFunc(instanceA, instanceB);
```

You could even combine this with [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), like this:

```
var foo = new MyClass<string>((a, b) => Math.Abs(a.Length - b.Length));
```

Comment: While correct, note that you don't have to use generics to make this work.

Comment: @LordTakkera Yes you're right, generics aren't absolutely necessary to answer the question, but I felt it would be helpful to illustrate their use in this case.

Comment: I just pointed it out because it sounds like the OP is not familiar with C#, and my have trouble understanding generics, let alone generics inside of a generic delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Func`, `Action`, and `delegates` to do this:

Action: http://www.dotnetperls.com/action

Func: http://www.dotnetperls.com/func

delegate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: `Func` and `Action` are also delegates.