# How to add a method into a constructor?

Tags: c#

I've got a problem. I know only how to use action and func, but the problem is that i need to put a method into a constructor like that.

```
Reader read = new Reader(1000, cki, method);
```

but the problem is that the method needs input like that.

```
public static void method(int Integer)
```

what do i do in that situation ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Action<int>` for the constructor parameter.The return type of `Action` is `void` and the generic argument is the parameter type.So it matches with your method which takes an `int` and returns `void`.

Comment: it says  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'

Comment: @Hui Keep your words in 1 comment as much as possible. That will be more clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a method, but you can use a Action

```
public Reader(int first, object cki, Action method)
{
    //ctor code here
    method.Invoke();
}
```

Than use:

```
var reader = new Reader(1000, cki, () => SomeMethod(123));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't pass a method.

Comment: yep i see Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'

Comment: is there another way ?

Comment: Why does it have to be a method? Theoretically, you could use Reflection and magic strings, but that would be awful and error prone. Could you update your question as to why does it have to be a method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `Action<int>` and call it from withing the constructor like following?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sample s = new Sample((i) => {Console.WriteLine(i);});
    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public Sample(Action<int> method)
    {
        method(5);
    }
}
```