# Unity3d, C# pass function as parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have `ScriptA` with a lot of `void` functions:

```
void methodOne() { 
   some code
}

void methodTwo(int a, int b) {
}
```

I want to pass to static method of another script. Lets say it `scriptB`:

```
ScriptB.staticMethod(methodOne, some, other, primitive, parameters);
ScriptB.staticMethod(methodTwo(a, b), some, other, parameters);
```

The main Idea of my scripts is that `ScriptB` will get datas from server and call methods that got from `ScriptA` to make changes in my game depending on data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.
But to answer your question, you can pass methods as parameters using delegates. Here is an example:

```
public class ScriptA
{
    public delegate void MethodOneDelegate(int a, int b);

    public void MethodOne(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
}

public static class ScriptB
{
    public static void StaticMethod(ScriptA.MethodOneDelegate function, int a, int b)
    {
        function(a, b);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    ScriptA scriptA = new ScriptA();
    ScriptB.StaticMethod(scriptA.MethodOne, 1, 2);
}
```

There is alternative solutions, you can take a look at System.Func and System.Action.

Comment: How code will distinguish that `MethodOneDelegate` is `MethodOne`s? I thought I need to assign values.

Comment: `MethodOneDelegate` only describes the signature of `MethodOne` (takes two integers and returns void).
The method that will be called by `StaticMethod` is provided as a parameter (scriptA.MethodOne).

Comment: Can I declare delgates inside of `ScriptB`? it will be like template for calling.

Comment: Yes of course `MethodOneDelegate` could be declared in `ScriptB` instead of `ScriptA`. Or anywhere else.

Comment: Please add links to System.Func and System.Action

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to start the methods when you put them as parameters? Or do you need the values from those methods?

Either way, you could do two things, either [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp) or just pass the name of the method as string and in your method check which name has been entered and start that method in your method.