# Passing method or function as parameter

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class for Lua scripts. I have a method called `Expose` which registers a function to the Lua environment.

```
protected void Expose(string name, MethodBase method)
    {
        this.Lua.RegisterFunction(name, this, method);
    }
```

However, I want to make it easier by passing the method name only instead of doing this:

```
this.Expose(this.GetType().GetMethod(...
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
this.Expose(LuaExports.DoSomething);
```

So instead of passing MethodBase, what do I need to pass? Note that the passed argument can be a method that returns something, or a method that does not return anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Why not pas the delegate?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams take it easy... just trying to help. I'm pretty sure you can't pass a single delegate that does both, which is why I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @DrewJordan Sorry, I just hate when people here immiediately mark posts as duplicates.

Comment: np. Sometimes it isn't, and sometimes it is... that's why my flag is marked as a *possible* duplicate, and needs some others to agree before being officially marked as such. Wouldn't be the first time I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need two methods, one that accepts an `Action` delegate (a void method) and the other that accepts a`Func<T>` delegate (a method that returns `T`):

```
protected void Expose(string name, Action method)
{
    method(); // will invoke the method passed.
}

protected void Expose(string name, Func<SomeType> method)
{
    var value = method(); // will invoke the method passed and assign return result to value.
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know the type of the Func? Also, how do I convert them to MethodBase? Lua.RegisterFunction takes MethodBase as parameter...

Comment: use 'object' or something... the solution that David gave you is able if you declare the class using the 'T' as generic type.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams, how can you not know it? Do you use the return value? If not, just use the first option and use `() =>  method()`  as the parameter. That way your method with a return gets called via an `Action` lambda and you only need that version.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I believe you can come is passing a delegate type directly:

```
protected void Expose(string name, Delegate delegate)
{
    this.Lua.RegisterFunction(name, d.Target, d.Method);
}
```

Although to be able to call this, you would have to create a delegate type, which can be done with a cast:

```
 this.Expose("Name", (Action)LuaExports.DoSomething);
```

If you don't want to have the cast you would have to write a whole bunch of genetic overloads of Expose that each take a separate delegate type:

```
Expose(string name, Action action);
Expose<T1>(string name, Action<T1> action);
Expose<T1, T2>(string name, Action<T1, T2> action);
...
Expose<T1, TResult>>(string name, Func<T1, TResult> action);
Expose<T1, T2, TResult>>(string name, Action<T1, T2, TResult>> action);
...
```