# Pass += or -= as a parameter in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method from a button click with the following code in c# (small golf scoring program I'm working on just for fun):

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnMinus.Enabled = true;
    if (f_intHoleNumber != 18) { f_intHoleNumber += 1; }
    if (f_intHoleNumber == 18) { btnPlus.Enabled = false; }
    txtHoleNumber.Text = f_intHoleNumber.ToString();            
}
```

I would like to refactor that and extract another method from it so I don't reuse code but i'm not sure if its possible to pass an operator (+=) as a parameter to a method.  Can this be done?

Comment: create two methods: First will increase your value, the second one - decrease. Whats a problem?

Comment: Simpler yet, pass the value: `f_intHoleNumber += value`, where `value` is `+1/-1` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. What about passing +1 or -1 to the method and multiplying it with the value to add or to subtract. 
For example:

```
public float calc(float val1, float val2, int op) 
{
    return val1 + op * val2;
}
```

Comment: Or simply pas in `-1 * value`.

Comment: Never even thought of that.  Good deal. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a method that does the adding and subtracting for you.  You probably want to go that route.
[Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there was a difference.

Comment: You are not really providing a solution, just a link to a solution. [That is more of a comment.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/245360)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `Func<int, int>` which accepts one int parameter and returns an int.

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleHoleChange(currentHole => currentHole + 1);      
}

private void HandleHoleChange(Func<int, int> getNextHoleFunc)
{
    btnMinus.Enabled = true;
    if (f_intHoleNumber != 18) { f_intHoleNumber = getNextHoleFunc(f_intHoldNumber); }
    if (f_intHoleNumber == 18) { btnPlus.Enabled = false; }
    txtHoleNumber.Text = f_intHoleNumber.ToString();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer allows to pass a `0` which would mess up the calculation. If you want only to allow for addition or subtraction you can use a boolean variable to specify it in the parameterlist:

```
public float calc(float val1, float val2, bool add) 
{
    int op = add ? 1 : -1;
    return val1 + op * val2;
}
```