# Is it possible to use a method as the first parameter to an extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I tried to do this:

```
public static EventHandler ToEventHandler(this Action callback)
{...}
```

for some syntactic sugar when I want to pass a simple method like `void x()` to a method that's typed for an `EventHandler`.

But when I try to call this like so:

```
SomeMethod(x.ToEventHandler());
```

I get a compiler error:

```
x() is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context
```

Since methods are first class citizens in .NET, I can't see why this shouldn't be possible. Why doesn't it like this, and is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp

Comment: Have you tried casting it to an `Action` first? It's a method group until the compiler knows otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because `x` is a method, and compiler won't magically turn a method by its identifier into a delegate when using extension methods (I believe it should be able to do so indeed...).

What you need is this: `SomeMethod(new Action(x).ToEventHandler());`

In the other hand, an `EventHandler` has two input parameters while you expect to use an `Action` (parameterless delegate...). I suspect that you're trying to this:

```
EventHandler handler = (sender, e) => callback();
```

...and then, if you're going this route, it's fine.