# How to pass a reference to a STATIC method as a function parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, nlog, method-parameters, swallowed-exceptions

I need to use a Swallow(Func) method from NLog library. 
Important note: I call Swallow from a static method and want to pass a static method.

Its documentation is here:

http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v3.2.1/html/Overload_NLog_Logger_Swallow.htm

The first case (`Swallow(Action)`) (passing static methods WO parameters) works straightforward:

```
static void ParameterlessMethodThatCasts ()
{
   throw NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
}

...
// Code in some method that uses static instance of nLog
nLog.Instance.Swallow( ParameterlessMethodThatCasts );
```

Unfortunately, there is no example provided for the 2nd (`Swallow<T>(Func<T>)`) and 3rd (`Swallow<T>(Func<T>, T)`) overload, in which both cases are passed method references with parameters.

I did not find appropriate example elsewhere either.

I have tried myself:

```
`Object.TypeOf()`
```

and 
    `var t = typeof(MyMethod);`

Neither of them are syntactically correct.

What syntax should I use here instead, to pass a ref to a method with parameters
(i.e. the second and third overload in the link above.) ?

Is there other way than passing a delegate ?

Comment: May be I will have to create a delegate and pass that, as suggested in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in a `Func<T>` or `Func<T, T>` if you will, but maybe it is more suitable for you to pass in an anonymous lambda expression:

```
() => this.ParameterlessMethodThatCasts("A", "B", 1, 2)
```

Since this signature matched the first overload, you can pass in any parameters you want.

The `Func<T>` and `Func<T, T>` would match a method like this (where `T` is `string` in this case):

```
private string SomeMethod(); // Func<T>
```

And this:

```
private string SomeMethod(string arg1); // Func<T, T>
```

Comment: Patrick: Thanx for tip. I forgot to specify, that it was a static method environment where I do it. I have fixed it in the question.

Comment: So how does that change my answer?

Comment: Patrick
You are right ! I removed the type specification Swallow<MyType> and it compiles now. Seems like its exactly what I want :) Let me check.

Comment: Okay. Nice! @Peter

Comment: Patrick: Thank you again! You just taught me how do I create an ad-hoc delegate for a local use and pass as an argument :) 
I wonder, if that increases instruction cycle consumption versus that option, where I create a static delegate and pass always that one.