# How to apply DRY principle to repeated C# for loops

Tags: c#

I keep going through a two dimensional array and would like to stop repeating the same nested for loops

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  for (int y =0; y < height; y++) {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

Is there a way to DRY-out the nested for loops to something more along the lines of

```
iterateThroughMatrix ( doSomeStuff )
iterateThroughMatrix ( doSomethingElse )
iterateThroughMatric ( doSomeOtherStuff )

void iterateThroughMatrix ( doSomething ) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y =0; y < height; y++) {
      // doSomething here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [how to pass methods as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
void iterateThroughMatrix(Action<int, int> doSomething)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            doSomething(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use any delegate that has two integers, but `Action<int, int>` is built-in and ready to go.