# Pass action delegate as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method which accepts an `Action` delegate and executes the given method as shown here:

```
public void ExpMethod(Action inputDel)
{
    inpuDel();
}
```

I can call above given method like this:

```
ExpMethod(() => {/*do something that matters*/});
```

Everything works fine. So far so good. Now I want to have a method which takes a generic `Action` delegate as an input parameter - like this:

```
public void ExpGenMethod(Action<string,int> inputDel)
{
    // I don't know how to call the supplied delegate as it requires parameters
}
```

Also, I am trying to call this `ExpGenMethod` in this way:

```
ExpGenMethod(("Hi",1) => {/*do something that makes sense*/});
```

But it shows syntax errors. Please let me know how to use generic action delegate in this case?

Comment: If the caller is supplying "input", the input should be absorbed into the body of the lambda, not as parameters - so your existing method should still work and `"Hi"` and `1` wouldn't be on the left of the `=>`.

Comment: What error *do* you get? Please show the exact message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The whole point of a delegate is to have a pointer to a method. Passing parameters to it while it´s being declared is therefor pointless. Instead pass the arguments for your delegate within the method that *executes* the delegate, in your case within `ExpGenMethod`:

You should do this instead:

```
public void ExpGenMethod(Action<string,int> inputDel)
{
    inputDel("Hi", 1);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
ExpGenMethod((x, y) => {/*do something that makes sense*/});
```

When executing that delegate `x` evaluates to `"Hi"` and `y` to `1`.

Comment: Are you expecting the parameters to be `"Hi", 1` always ?

Comment: @VinodSrivastav Of course not. Those values shpuld be computed by whatever code - either within that method or via args passed to it. The point of the answer just was the param-values are not **part of** the delegate. Instead they are **passed to** it.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, you'll want the heavy lifting to happen *in* the ExpGenMethod and in the delegate itself you'll simply be passing the parameters to the ExpGenMethod.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ExpGenMethod((options) =>
        {
            options.x = "Hi";
            options.y = 1;
        });
    }

    public static void ExpGenMethod(Action<Options> inputDel)
    {
        var options = new Options();
        inputDel(options);
        /* have access to x and y so do some thing useful with these values */
        Console.WriteLine(options.x);
        Console.WriteLine(options.y);
    }
}

public class Options
{
    public string x { set; get;}

    public int y { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Well appreciated answer, @Sangeet you save my time.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me what is the advantage of abstracting away the x and y arguments into an Options class, and then passing said Options instance using a Lambda function?

Answer (score 6):

`(a,b) => {/*do something that matters*/}` means  that a and b are parameters which are going to be specified during the call. Here you are using constant so you should do something like `() => { use "Hi"; use 1;}` and that would get you back to your first working example.

If you want to pass parameter you cna do it this way:

```
public void work()
{
    ExpGenMethod((a) => {/*do something that matters*/});
}

public void ExpGenMethod(Action<int> inputDel, int parameterToUse)
{
    inputDel(parameterToUse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on to what @HimBromBeere explained:

The keyword Action is defined as delegate:

```
public delegate void Action<in T1, in T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

So if the method is defined as:

```
public void ExpGenMethod(Action<string,int> inputDel)
{
    inputDel("Hi", 1);
}
```

You can call ExpGenMethod with parameters x,y is using a Lambda expression, and see the results using Console.Writeline as follows:

```
ExpGenMethod((x, y) => { Console.WriteLine($"{x} {y}"); });
```