# Shorthand for initializing delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, shorthand

Let's say I had a method that took a delegate as a parameter, like this:

```
public delegate void SampleDelegate(int foo);

public void DoSomething(SampleDelegate del) 
{
    //Does something
}
```

Would there be a shorthand for doing something like this?

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    void bar(int foo) {
        int x = foo;
    } 
    DoSomething(bar);
}
```

Or is this the most efficient way to do this?

Ideally, I would do something like this:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    DoSomething(void(int foo) {
        int x = foo;
    });
}
```

but that generates syntax errors. Is there a proper syntax for doing something like the above?

Comment: You're looking for anonymous methods or lambdas.

Comment: @Tim_Schmelter The ideal approach I showed would make for cleaner code by not using the variable name bar and simpliyfing things into a few lines.

Comment: How do you qualify "most efficient"? Performance? Characters?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Characters

Comment: Seems like this would to exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression to create a function as an expression:

```
DoSomething(myInt => { ... });
```

You don't need to declare `SampleDelegate` either. You can use `Action<int>`.