# Passing function as parameter to another function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my app I have some functions that loop over all the components in a form to establish some properties like the following ones:

Function used to set all the textbox in a form to readonly when we are just viewing data:

```
public void SetReadOnly(Control.ControlCollection controls, bool readOnly)
{
    foreach(var panel in controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        SetReadOnly(panel.Controls, readOnly);
    }

    foreach(var tabpageview in controls.OfType<TabPageView>())
    {
        foreach(var tabpageviewpage in tabpage.Controls)
        {
            SetReadOnly(tagpageviewpage.Controls, readOnly);
        }
    }

    foreach(var textbox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textbox.ReadOnly = readOnly;
    }
}
```

Function used to clean the content of all the textboxes after data has been inserted in the database:

```
public void CleanTextBox(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach(var panel in controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        CleanTextBox(panel.Controls);
    }

    foreach(var tabpageview in controls.OfType<TabPageView>())
    {
        foreach(var tabpageviewpage in tabpage.Controls)
        {
            CleanTextBox(tagpageviewpage.Controls);
        }
    }

    foreach(var textbox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textbox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Function that receives a list of fields and paint the labels with that name to red to remark that is required:

```
public void SetRequired(Control.ControlCollection controls, List<string> requiredFields)
{
    foreach(var panel in controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        SetRequired(panel.Controls, requiredFields);
    }

    foreach(var tabpageview in controls.OfType<TabPageView>())
    {
        foreach(var tabpageviewpage in tabpage.Controls)
        {
            SetRequired(tagpageviewpage.Controls, requiredFields);
        }
    }

    foreach(var field in requiredFields)
    {
        FindLabelByName(field).Foreground(Color.Red);
    }
}
```

As you can see all those function has something in common where they receive a collection of controls and loop over them. If it is a panel, a tabpageview, or another component with children, then it loops again until it find its textboxes and do some action.

Is it possible to make one function that receives another function as a parameter so if I start using groupboxes I can just put it in one function instead of having to put it in all the functions? Something like this.

```
public void LoopComponents(Control.ControlCollection controls, xxx function)
{
    foreach(var panel in controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        LoopComponents(panel.controls, function);
    }

    foreach(var tabpageview in controls.OfType<TabPageView>())
    {
        foreach(var tabpageviewpage in tabpageview.Controls)
        {
            LoopComponents(tabpageviewpage.Controls, function);
        }
    }

    function();
}

public void SetReadOnly(Control.ControlCollection controls, bool readOnly)
{
    foreach(var textbox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textbox.ReadOnly = readOnly;
    }
}

public void CleanTextBox(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach(var textbox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textbox.Text = "";
    }
}

public void SetRequired(Control.ControlCollection controls, List<string> requiredFields)
{
    foreach(var field in requiredFields)
    {
        FindLabelByName(field).Foreground(Color.Red);
    }
}   

public void Test()
{
    LoopComponents(Controls, SetReadOnly(Controls, true));
    LoopComponents(Controls, CleanTextBox(Controls));
    LoopComponents(Controls, SetRequired(Controls, requiredFieldsList));
}
```

Currently I'm using C# 4.0, but if it's possible in a later version it doesn't matter, just curious to know if it's possible. Thanks

Comment: Please check; [Pass Method as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp) this might be helpful for you.

Comment: I saw that thread. The difference is that in that example the functions always receive a string and return something, while in my case the functions receive different parameters. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You might want to look into the Visitor Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a delegate or use Predefined ones, Like Action<> and Func<>. 
Delegates will defines a method signature:

```
 delegate void Operator(Control.ControlCollection controls);
```

and you can modify LoadComponent in this way:

```
 LoadComponent(Control.ControlCollection controls, Operator Op)
 {
     foreach(var control in controls.OfType<Panel>())
     {
        Op(panel.controls);
     }
     //....
 }
```

and you can write some function as Operator, Like:

```
 public void CleanTextBox(Control.ControlCollection controls)
 {
     foreach(var textbox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
     {
        textbox.Text = "";
     }
 }
```

**Note:** in Above function `CleanTextBox` inputs and outputs are the same in Operator delegate. so it will matches to Operator delegate.

**Use Predefined delegates:**

you can use either predefined delegates. As your functions are void, you can use one of the Action's overloads:

```
 LoadComponent(Action<Control.ControlCollection controls, Action<Control.ControlCollection> Op)
 {
     foreach(var control in controls.OfType<Panel>())
     {
        Op(panel.controls);
     }
     //....
 }
```

this new version just removed the delegate deceleration.
in both fashion of the work you can use this code to do your operation on the data's:

```
LoopComponents(Controls, CleanTextBox(Controls));
```

** Func delegates are useful when you want to have a return value**

**Edit:** If you want to Call different method with a single delegate you must create new method to unify these methods:

rewrite `LoadComponents`:

```
  LoadComponents(Control.ControlCollection controls, Action Op)
  {
       Op.Invoke();
       //....
  }
```

(This is Lambda Expression to unify your methods)

```
 LoadComponents(Controls, new Action(()=>{ SetRequired(Controls,true);}));
 LoopComponents(Controls, new Action(()=>{ CleanTextBox(Controls);})); 
 LoopComponents(Controls, new Action(()=>{ SetRequired(Controls, requiredFieldsList);});
```

Comment: Yes, I read about that, but my functions have different signatures, so I would need three delegates and one `LoadComponent` function for every delegate, having the same problem if I want to loop over a new type of control.

Comment: I have added some way to do what you wanted.