# How to pass a function with parameters to a function?

Tags: c#, function, oop, methods

I want to do something like this

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;

int performAction(int var1, int var2) {
    return var1 + var2;
}

//accepts function with parameters as parameter
void runLater(performAction(x, y));
```

The values of x and y could change before `performAction` is run.

Comment: Hint. Search on these terms: method pointer / delegate / Func<>

Comment: Delegates are the droids you are looking for. | Technically you could also make a interface, write a concerete class that implements it, make a instance and then hand it it. But you got Delegates, so that is only overly complex. I just mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: `void runLater(Action act);` usage: `runLater(() => performAction(x, y));`. You're passing in an anonymous function that has references to `x` and `y`.

Comment: I would suggest to have a closer look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766484/5174469)

Comment: @MongZhu That was exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: I'm nominating this to be re-opened because the duplicate link doesn't seem to address variable capture which is a central element of this question.

Comment: @Ruzihm " variable capture which is a central element of this question." what makes you think so? could you explain?

Comment: @MongZhu this part "The values of x and y could change before performAction is run." means that not just any delegate or function passing will work. [user1538301's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58544934/1092820) below should work for you

Comment: @Ruzihm I think this needs more clarification from OP's side. I would need more information before I would reopen this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature would be:

```cs
void runLater(Func<int, int, int> functionParameter);
```

You'd call it exactly as shown above in your question;

```cs
runLater(performAction);
```

If you need it to be performed the parameters provided outside of `runLater`:

```cs
// signature would be:
void runLater(Func<int> functionParameter);
// invocation like:
var x = 2;
var y = 3;
runLater(delegate () { return performAction(x, y);});
// or
runLater(() => performAction(x, y));
```

Comment: You define runLater as taking a function that takes two parameters, but you pass it a function that takes no parameters. Then you are passing runLater a delegate that calls runLater.

Comment: performAction as defined in the question is a function that takes two ints and returns an int (`Func<int, int, int>`)

Comment: Please fix your code so that it compiles.

Comment: It definitely compiles.. I omitted a semi-colon and a parameter name which has since been fixed. Other than that, it compiles.

Comment: Please fix your code so that it can be compiled by a standard-compliant C# compiler.

Comment: https://repl.it/@piboistudios/str-replace

Comment: It's the exact same code, I literally just put a Console.WriteLine and a Main function so it runs as a program.

Comment: Right.. I made a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can remove `runLater(Func<int, int, int> functionParameter)`, as it is unused. No need for OP to spend time wondering what it's there for.