# Is it necessary to use () with the Contains method?

Tags: c#, list, linq, enumerable

I have code looking like this:

```cs
string target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains);
```

I didn't write the code and I am trying to understand what it does.  I saw there is a method called `Contains()` but cannot understand here why there are no () after the `Contains`.  Is this a different thing? Can someone explain what this code is doing?

[image]

Comment: `Contains` is a function, `Contains(..)` is a call to the function.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` basically takes a function as argument. Writing

```cs
ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains);
```

is practically the same as writing

```cs
ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(x => e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains(x));
```

Both `Contains` and `x => Contains(x)` are functions, so it works!

Comment: Also, even if the second line of code is more readable and easy to understand it have a cost as it create new objects.

Comment: @Orace [Not true](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgBgARwIwDoAyBLAdgRwG4BYAKDgGYUAmJAYSQG8ylWkAHAJ2wDcBDAC4BTFKmQB7bgHM8fADYAVPpylCBJUmyQs2lUcgCyACjQIA2gF0kYAJRMdW1nADs19ADFsnAM4CA8pwAIkIAZnwArnICRmBIALwAfEiS2DK48koqauh04rgCfHjeMTY2GloAvg7amrpUpkgAciZiltZ2zLWOKK5gHl6+AcFhkdEpaRnKqgI5eQVFZdVVpBVAA=)

Comment: @canton7 The link you provided shows the compiler for lambda-version unnecessarily defines a new `[CompilerGenerated]` method `<M>b__1_0(String)` - while this *won't* result in any GC heap allocations (and the JIT will probably inline the function) it's disappointing that the C# compiler doesn't automatically inline trivial lambdas.

Comment: @Orace That question compares creating a delegate vs not creating one, and the delegate is capturing. Neither of the delegates in the question above are capturing

Comment: @Dai Yeah I found that odd -- I already [asked about that on gitter](https://gitter.im/dotnet/csharplang?at=5e3bdab1f301780b836c21b5). I'm presuming it would be a pointless optimization. It's also unusual that the compiler isn't caching the generated delegate: normally it does

Comment: @canton7 in some case there is a context capture : https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgBgARwIwDoAyBLAdgRwG4BYAKDgGYUAmJAYSQG8ylWXWUq1kBZACm5IA9gCdsAczwBDADYAVKSPEBTAC4AaFKgQBtALpIwASibsOHOAHZD6AGLYRAZ1UB5EQBFlAMykBXGap8YEgAvAB8wmKSuLIKSmrodEK4qlJ4jkFGRiSk5gC+ZkiFlFrIAHIC2pES0vKKKhql+oYmzLnmFtZgdg7Obp4+/oGiNTF18aqJyanp2YUFpHlAA=]

Comment: @Orace Correct, but not in this answer, and certainly not in "the second line of code", as you claimed

Comment: @canton7 We don't know where `e` is declared, is it in the local context or is it a field of current object ? By case convention it's probably a parameter of the current method and belong to the local context and need to be captured.

Comment: @Orace That's fair. Your original comment could do with some clarification, then

Answer (score 1):

You dont need it because `FirstOrDefault` take a `Func` in parameter. Since `Contains` match the type asked, you can pass `Contains` like you would pass any argument to any other function.

FirstOrDefault's signature is:

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,bool> predicate);
```

You are used to write:

```
var target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(x => e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains(x));
```

Which is the same as

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = x => e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains(x);
var target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

Which is the same as

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains;
var target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

At that point, you can pass `Contains` directly:

```
var target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` accepts a `Func<TSource, bool>` as it's argument.

Normally this would be a lambda expression, but as `string.Contains` can be cast to a `Func<string, bool>`, it can be passed to the method directly (assuming `ListOfTabs` is `IEnumerable<string>`).

In the implementation of `FirstOrDefault`, the `()` syntax will be used to actually execute `string.Contains`.