# Call class method as parameter

Tags: c#

It is possible to do something like this on C#? I want a generic void for calling differents methods from another class.

```
public class custom{
   public void A(){}
   public void B(){}
}

void doSomething(List<custom> laux, method m ){
    foreach(var aux in laux){
        aux.m; //something like this
    }
}

void main(){
   doSomething(new List<custom>(),A);
   doSomething(new List<custom>(),B);
}
```

Comment: are you talking about delegates, Actions, Func https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something *close* to this via an `Action` delegate:

```
void doSomething(List<custom> laux, Action<custom> m ){
    foreach(var aux in laux){
        m(aux);
    }
}

void main(){
   doSomething(new List<custom>(),c=> c.A());
   doSomething(new List<custom>(),c=> c.B());
}
```