# Adding a function as an object's property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project I'm implementing an action class and was wondering if it was possible to pass a function as a parameter like this:

```
public class Action : MonoBehavior {
  public int ID;
  public string Name;
  //Test variable to store a function here
}
```

Where later I would create a function, such as this one, and call it.

```
void TestFunction() {
  print("Test");
}
public Action ExampleAction;
ExampleAction.Test = TestFunction();
```

And then finally I could simply call "Action.Test" to run TestFunction.

I've done some research on the topic and I believe it's somewhat related to delegation but how could I do it in this scenario?

And even more, is this sort of implementation reliable or the nicest way to do it? In my project I plan on having a lot of toggleable actions, that when clicked, will continuously do a large variety of different things.

Comment: You can store delegates. Define the function signature and then you can just directly assign it. Then calling it can be done by referencing the stored delegate. `public void YourDelegate(parameters);`. Then save a reference of it `private YourDelegate = null`. Then assign it with a function of the same signature (scope, return type and parameters).

Comment: In your case it would simply be [`public System.Action Test;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action)

Comment: Also related btw [Pass method as parameter using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp) -> between "pass" and "store" there is little difference ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, what you are trying to do is create a parameterized delegate.

I think `UnityAction` fit this perfectly.
`UnityAction` is a built-in delegate that takes no parameters and returns no value.

In your case, you would want to use a parameterized `UnityAction<T1, T2>`, where you would set `T1` to int and `T2` to string.

Here is a snippet for demonstration:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class UnityActionDemo
{
    UnityAction<int, string> action;
    private void Start()
    {
        action = TestMethod;
    }

    public void TestMethod(int id, string name)
    {
        Debug.Log("id is: " + id + "\t name is: " + name);
    }
}
```

`action` can then be passed around to any method that takes a `UnityAction<int, string>` as a parameter.

In order to invoke the method, call `action.Invoke` with the parameters you'd like to use:

```
action.Invoke(27, "A cool method name");
```

:)

Comment: Never understood the purpose of `UnityAction` to be honest ... There already is `System.Action<T1,T2>` which does exactly the same ... So either it does some additional stuff or is pretty much redundant

Comment: I'm not sure about it myself. Maybe the internal implementations are more optimized to how Unity works? Just shooting in the dark.