# How to create a function that receives as a parameter a dynamic function?

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.android, dynamic-programming

I'm creating a dynamic dialog box in `xamarin.android` and I want the dialog box to receive a function that it will execute upon clicking the action button.

Heres my code:

```cs
public static void ShowDialogBox(Context context, Function dynamicFunction)
{
    Dialog popupDialog = new Dialog(context);
    popupDialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.dialog_dynamic);
    popupDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
    popupDialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
    popupDialog.Show();

    TextView title = popupDialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dialog_title);
    TextView content = popupDialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dialog_content);
    ImageView icon = popupDialog.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.dialog_icon);
    Button actionButton = popupDialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_action_button);

    popupDialog.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.dialog_close).Click += delegate { popupDialog.Dismiss(); };
    popupDialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_cancel_button).Click += delegate { popupDialog.Dismiss(); };
    
    actionButton.Click += dynamicFunction;
}
```

*Take note that the Function parameter is just an example. Also I will make the text and content in this dialog box a parameter.

Example scenario:

1. If I send GetCurrentDate function to this dialog box, when the action button is clicked it will get the current date.
2. If I send OpenBluetooth function to this dialog box, when the action button is clicked it will open the Bluetooth

It is possible to send another function to this `ShowDialogBox` function and run it when the action button is clicked? My purpose here it to make my code clean and easy to use.

Comment: Have you already looked into using Delegates? You can use a delegate as a parameter and this will basically be the function to execute dynamically.
Here is a question already answered with the same requirement as your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp

Comment: from my experience, a shared dialog (or form) is a dead-end road. I mean that the cost of the business layer/UI to be able to adapt to many (different) situations and the cost of creating several components is 99% of times in favor of the latter. If you want, you may gain some advantage with a clever composition-pattern, but -again- not worth it if the dialogs are pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object orientation can help you: you can abstract your function into a class and then derive any specilized function class to implement your specific action.
Something like the following:

```
abstract class ActionClassBase
{
    public abstract void Action();

    private string data = "";
    public string Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }
}

class GetCurrentDateAction : ActionClassBase
{
    public override void Action()
    {
        Data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}

class OpenBlueToothAction : ActionClassBase
{
    public override void Action()
    {
        Data = "BlueTooth opened";
    }
}


public static void ShowDialogBox(Context context, ActionClassBase action)
{
    Dialog popupDialog = new Dialog(context);
    popupDialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.dialog_dynamic);
    popupDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
    popupDialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
    popupDialog.Show();

    TextView title = popupDialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dialog_title);
    TextView content = popupDialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dialog_content);
    ImageView icon = popupDialog.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.dialog_icon);
    Button actionButton = popupDialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_action_button);

    popupDialog.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.dialog_close).Click += delegate { popupDialog.Dismiss(); };
    popupDialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_cancel_button).Click += delegate { popupDialog.Dismiss(); };

    actionButton.Click += (sender, ev) => action.Action();
}
```

Further with this approach it's very easy to add new functions: just derive a new class and override the `Action()` method

Comment: Another question is how can I close the dialog box using the `action.Action()`?

Comment: Why do you want to using `action.Action()` to close the dialog box? There is already a cancel_button in your code. In addition, closing the dialog box need to call the `Dismiss()` method. So if you want to close it with the `action.Action()`, you need to make ActionClassBase get the instance of the dialog and then call the `Dismiss()` method. @Elohist

Comment: I want to close it after execution of the `action.Action()`. How can I pass the my dialog box in `ActionClassBase`?

Comment: You can try the code in my answer.@Elohist

Comment: @Elohist just add a reference to `Window` and a bool flag to decide to close or not to the base class (set them inside the `ShowDialogBox` method). Then on each `Action` you can decide to close the dialog or not

Answer (score 2):

As @Nico already commented, you can use `Func` or a delegate as a parameter. I'd  suggest you use `Action` instead.

The [`Clicked` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-6.0) on `Xamarin.Forms.Button` uses an event handler with the signature `void OnClicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)`. Therefore, your signature would use a `Action<object?, EventArgs>` parameter.

A couple things to note:

- If you don't use nullable reference types in your project, omit the question marks
- You need to check the parameter for `null` before assigning it to the `Clicked` event
- Invoking an `Action` does not return anything. If you want to "get the current date", your action must write the current date in a field or control
- If your function needs other parameters, you need to pass a delegate (or wrap your function call in a function with the `sender` and `e` parameters: `ShowDialogBox(context, (sender, e) => MyFunction("other data"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dialog in the ActionClassBase and call the `Dismiss()` method in the `Action()`. Such as

```
abstract class ActionClassBase
{
  public  Dialog popupDialog;
  public abstract void Action();

  private string data = "";
  public string Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }
  }

class GetCurrentDateAction : ActionClassBase
{
  public override void Action()
  {
    Data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    base.popupDialog.Dismiss();
  }
}

class OpenBlueToothAction : ActionClassBase
{
  public override void Action()
  {
    Data = "BlueTooth opened";
    base.popupDialog.Dismiss();
  }
}
```

And then, pass the dialog to the ActionClassBase in the `ShowDialogBox(Context context, Function dynamicFunction)` . Such as:

```
Dialog popupDialog = new Dialog(context);
popupDialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.dialog_dynamic);
popupDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
popupDialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
dynamicFunction.popupDialog = popupDialog;
```