# return type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to `c#` and here is an excerpt from a personal project i am working on to get some experience.

When calling the `getRecipe()` function outside this class i am presented with the following error. I want to keep my `List` private to the `CookBook` class but still be able to get a reference to one of the `Recipes` in the `List`. I do not want to make my `List` public.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks

---

**The error**

```
return type 'cookbook.Recipe is less accessible than method 'cookbook.CookBook.getRecipe(string)'
```

---

```
public class CookBook
{
    private List<Recipe> listOfRecipes = new List<Recipe> {};
    public Recipe getRecipe(string name)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (listOfRecipes[i].getRecipeName() != name)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return listOfRecipes[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a few suggestions: You can use LINQ to make the code more concise: `return listOfRecipes.FirstOrDefault(recipe => recipe.getRecipeName().Equals(name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));`. Your current code will fail if a recipe that doesn't exist is requested (it will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException), also it will do a case sensitive comparison (So 'cake' will not find 'Cake'). As a last suggestion, don't use names like getRecipeName or getRecipe. Use PascalCase (GetRecipe), and consider properties/indexers (CookBook["Cake"] or CookBoox.Recipes["Cake"], Recipe.Name).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am looking into LINQ right now.

Comment: What does the "=>" mean in the linq statement you posted?

Comment: It's a lambda function. I'm basically declaring a function (a so-called "Predicate") `private bool DoesRecipeMatch(Recipe recipe, string name){ return recipe.getRecipeName().Equals(name,StringComparison...); }` and the LINQ Statement then does `foreach(Recipe recipe in listOfRecipes) { if(DoesRecipeMatch(recipe,name)) { return recipe; } return default(Recipe); }`. In other words, it does more or less what you do (apart from the bug in the iteration), but it's more concise and focuses on your intent (find a recipe whose name matches) rather than the individual steps (iterate, compare, return)

Comment: Also see Joseph Daigle's answer on this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Make the `Recipe` class public.

Comment: I forgot that classes in c# are private by default... thanks.

Comment: @prolink007: Classes are `internal` by default, not `private`. In fact, only nested classes can be `private`.

Answer (score 11):

Your Recipe class is less accessible than the method. You should check that Recipe is not private/internal and that you can see the Recipe class from outside that class scope (quick fix declare Recipe a public class).

As pointed out by Michael Stum in a comment below classes without an access modifier are by default either internal or private (if it's a nested class). This is possibly where your issue is and you may have just declared `class Recipe` instead of `public class Recipe`

Comment: Just to add since he is new: Any class without a modifier is internal my default, except for nested classes which are private (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error?

```
private List<Recipe> listOfRecipes = new List<Recipe> {};
```

should be:

```
private List<Recipe> listOfRecipes = new List<Recipe>();
```

Additionally, you could simply use LINQ to get your result, I'm not in VS, but something like this...

```
public Recipe getRecipe(string name)
{
    return listOfRecipes.Where(c => c.RecipeName == name).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Me too - I would have thought that wouldn't compile at first glance :)

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ suggestion, looking into it now.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message clearly states, the `Recipe` class is less accessible (eg, not `public`) than your method.

Answer (score 0):

Make Your Class Public ..Without That U cannot Return Anything

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the extent if visibility of 'Recipe' class is covers where you want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, by default, classes are `private`, So the access level is limited.
Declaring your model class as public (Recipe) as `public`.

Answer (score -1):

Make the method internal. Hope it will work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you can tell the answer for this question was already accepted about 5 years ago. If you would like to add additional details to the answers that already exist, please try to be more descriptive in your answers. Thanks!