# Unable to fill the datagridview using Generics list

Tags: c#, list, generics, dataset

I don't understand what the problem is with the following simple code. All it does is take a list and display it in the datagridview. This is the error I get :

> *Error    1   Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   is less accessible than method
>   'WindowsFormsApplication10.Form1.FillGridView()'*

Also, is there a way to convert your list, arraylist etc into a dataset type?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public List<Student> FillGridView ()
    {
        List<Student> l = new List<Student> ();
        l.Add (new Student { Fname="bloke", Lname="lll", Contact=293489485});
        l.Add (new Student { Fname = "dog", Lname = "assdf", Contact = 35345 });
        l.Add (new Student { Fname = "mary", Lname = "sdff", Contact = 6456 });
        l.Add (new Student { Fname = "john", Lname = "sdfsdf", Contact = 45656 });
        return l;


    }


    private void Form1_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = this.FillGridView ();
    }

    private void button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: your method is named FillGridView so I would expect it to fill a grid view. But it doesn't. You might want to find a better name (CreateStudentList or something) to fit it's behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804603/return-type-is-less-accessible-than-method

Is your Student class private/protected?

Comment: can you share your `Student` class ?

Answer (score 2):

Does your method need to be public? It looks like your student class is not public, so returning a list of it to any public caller is inconsistent. As it looks, your method can be private.

```
private List<Student> FillGridView()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student` class access modifier is probably `non-public`.

It doesn't make sense for a `public` method of a type that is `non-public`. *How could the method works itself to external assemblies?*

You can change your `FillGridView` access modifier to `private`

```
private List<Student> FillGridView ()
```

Read more information from [`Access Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

From [`C# Language Specification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

> **10.3.6 Constituent types**
>
> Types that are used in the declaration of a member are called the
>   constituent types of that member. Possible constituent types are the
>   type of a constant, field, property, event, or indexer, the return
>   type of a method or operator, and the parameter types of a method,
>   indexer, operator, or instance constructor. The constituent types of a
>   member must be at least as accessible as that member itself (§3.5.4).