# How do I set parts of an array to a random value in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, numbers

I'm new to programming so please bear with me!

I am trying to set the parts of an array to random values, but whenever I run the program it sets all parts of the array to the same value. I want them all to be different.

Here is my code:

```
int[] hello_array = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Here");

        Random rndm = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j < hello_array.Length; j++)
        {
            hello_array[j] = rndm.Next(99);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now Here");

        for (int i = 0; i < hello_array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hahahaha look at this " + hello_array[0]);
```

I'm probably completely missing it, but I can't tell what's wrong with my code! Can someone please tell me how I would make it so that all ten parts of the array generate different random numbers?

Answer (score 9):

Change this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("hahahaha look at this " + hello_array[0]);
```

to this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("hahahaha look at this " + hello_array[i]);
```

You were printing the same element in the array on every loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: @LewisAnderson please don't forget to mark the answer you found most helpful with the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

With the same number of lines, you could use some of the newer C# features to accomplish the same result (but without all the messy details).

You'd define a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes two parameters: a [*lambda expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/167343/1106367) (for instance, `() => random.Next(99)`) and the number of elements to generate. Inside the method, you'd use the [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword to return a new element generated by the factory.

```
Random random = new Random();
foreach (var element in Generate(() => random.Next(99), 10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> factory, int elements)
{
    for (int generated = 0; generated < elements; generated++)
    {
        yield return factory();
    }
}
```

Comment: A little overkill for such a simple example, I think. If you're going to rewrite it, why not just use: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Console.WriteLine("hahahaha look at this " + rndm.Next(99)); }` :P