# Having trouble with LINQ left join on List<FileInfo>

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<FileInfo>` lists, `SourceFiles` and `DestFiles`.  I want to build a LINQ query that will return a list of the items whose filenames are in `Source` but not in `Dest`, i.e. a left join.

My data set for `SourceFiles` is:

```
folder1\a.txt
folder1\b.txt
folder1\c.txt
folder1\d.txt
```

`DestFiles` is:

```
folder2\a.txt
folder2\b.txt
folder2\c.txt
```

so the query should return  `folder1\d.txt`.

Following the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx), I've tried using LINQ syntax:

```
var queryX = from s in SourceFiles
             join d in DestFiles
             on s.Name equals d.Name
             into SourceJoinDest
             from joinRow in SourceJoinDest.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 joinRow.FullName
             };
```

and using extension methods:

```
var query = SourceFiles.GroupJoin(DestFiles,
                                    source => source.Name,
                                    dest => dest.Name,
                                    (source,dest) => new
                                    {
                                        path = source.FullName
                                    }).Select(x => x.path.DefaultIfEmpty())
```

But neither one of these work; the LINQ syntax version returns `Object reference not sent to an instance of an object` and the extension version returns `Enumeration yielded no results.`

I realize that these queries are only returning sets of `FullName` properties and not the full `FileInfo` objects; I have code that takes each `FullName` and returns a `FileInfo`, and does this for each item in the query to rebuild the list.  But if there's a way to return a `FileInfo` directly from the query, that would be great.

Comment: What's the difference between FullName and Name? Does FullName include the whole path, or does Name have that as well?

Comment: Those are detailed in the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for the `FileInfo` class: `Name` is just the filename and extension, while `FullName` includes the full path

Comment: Doh! Forgot that it was a .NET class. I thought it was custom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `Join` is the ideal tool here. Basically you're looking for an `Except`. The built in `Except` doesn't have the overload to specify your properties through lambda. You will have to  create your own `IEqualityComparer`. You could do it, however, like this:

```
var excepts = SourceFiles.Where(c => !DestFiles.Any(p => p.Name == c.Name)).ToList();
```

Or, to select just the full path, you can use `Select` at the end.

```
var excepts = SourceFiles.Where(c => !DestFiles.Any(p => p.Name == c.Name))
                         .Select(f => f.FullName).ToList();
```

---

I would suggest having extension methods to do quick `Except` and `Intersect`.

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Except<R, S, T, U>(this IEnumerable<R> mainList, 
                                                IEnumerable<S> toBeSubtractedList,
                                                Func<R, T> mainListFunction, 
                                                Func<S, T> toBeSubtractedListFunction,
                                                Func<R, U> resultSelector)
{
    return EnumerateToCheck(mainList, toBeSubtractedList, mainListFunction, 
                            toBeSubtractedListFunction, resultSelector, false);
}

static IEnumerable<U> EnumerateToCheck<R, S, T, U>(IEnumerable<R> mainList, 
                                                   IEnumerable<S> secondaryList,
                                                   Func<R, T> mainListFunction, 
                                                   Func<S, T> secondaryListFunction,
                                                   Func<R, U> resultSelector,
                                                   bool ifFound)
{
    foreach (var r in mainList)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var s in secondaryList)
        {
            if (object.Equals(mainListFunction(r), secondaryListFunction(s)))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found == ifFound)
            yield return resultSelector(r);
    }

    //or may be just
    //return mainList.Where(r => secondaryList.Any(s => object.Equals(mainListFunction(r), secondaryListFunction(s))) == ifFound)
    //               .Select(r => resultSelector(r));
    //but I like the verbose way.. easier to debug..
}

public static IEnumerable<U> Intersect<R, S, T, U>(this IEnumerable<R> mainList, 
                                                   IEnumerable<S> toIntersectList,
                                                   Func<R, T> mainListFunction,
                                                   Func<S, T> toIntersectListFunction,
                                                   Func<R, U> resultSelector)
{
    return EnumerateToCheck(mainList, toIntersectList, mainListFunction, 
                            toIntersectListFunction, resultSelector, true);
}
```

Now in your case you can do just:

```
var excepts = SourceFiles.Except(DestFiles, p => p.Name, p => p.Name, p => p.FullName)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Works great, and very concise.  LINQ has been the most difficult thing for me to learn in .NET; can you recommend any sites that have well-written tutorials about lambda/extension trickery like this?

Comment: @sigil to be honest I have felt the same too to start with Linq and lambda, but to tell you once I have got a hang of it, its so simple and very very useful tool to know. To start with Linq you can start [from our own Jon Skeet's material](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx). which is really really good. But knowing lambda and `Func` will be important there, so start from [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this). Do not forget to read a bit about `deferred execution` when learning Linq.

Comment: hm, i'm seeing some odd behavior with the unit test on this.  i've made an expected result `List<FileInfo> expectedResult = new List<FileInfo>(); expectedResult.Add(new FileInfo(@"u:\folder1\d.txt"));` which should be identical to the result in `excepts`.  But when I compare them using `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(result, expectedResult);` the test fails.  The paths are the same--why does the test fail?  (i can post this as a new question if need be)

Comment: Not very sure Sigil, we could give a better idea if you make it another question with a proper sample data set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `join` you might be able to handle this with [`.Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var enumerable = sourceFiles.Except(destFiles, new FileInfoComparer<FileInfo>((f1, f2)=>f1.Name == f2.Name, f=>f.Name.GetHashCode()));
```

`.Except()` takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which you can write yourself or use a wrapper that takes a lambda.

```
    class FileInfoComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public FileInfoComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
        {
            _equals = equals;
            _getHashCode = getHashCode;
        }

        readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals;
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return _equals(x, y);
        }

        readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCode;
        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return _getHashCode(obj);
        }
    }
```

Running it with a few sample data results in the one `FileInfo` object which contains `"d.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it. But you need to take only those source files, which do not have joined destination files:

```
var query = from s in SourceFiles
            join d in DestFiles
                on s.Name equals d.Name into g
            where !g.Any() // empty group!
            select s;
```