# Why does this CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() test fail?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045758/having-trouble-with-linq-left-join-on-listfileinfo/), I'm working on a method that returns the elements from one `List<FileInfo>` that are not present in another `List<FileInfo>`.  I've implemented Nawfal's solution as follows:

```
public List<FileInfo> SourceNotInDest(List<FileInfo> SourceFiles, List<FileInfo> DestFiles)
{
 var notInDest = SourceFiles.Where(c => !DestFiles.Any(p => p.Name == c.Name)).ToList();
 return notInDest;
}
```

My data set for SourceFiles is:

```
u:\folder1\a.txt
u:\folder1\b.txt
u:\folder1\c.txt
u:\folder1\d.txt
```

DestFiles is:

```
u:\folder2\a.txt
u:\folder2\b.txt
u:\folder2\c.txt
```

When I step through the code and examine the lists' values, this appears to return the expected result.  But the unit test fails with the following code:

```
public void SourceNotInDestTest()
    {
        //arrange
        FileListComparer flc = new FileListComparer(); //class that has the list compare method
        FolderReader fr = new FolderReader(); //class for getting FileInfo from folder
        List<FileInfo> expectedResult = new List<FileInfo>();
        expectedResult.Add(new FileInfo(@"U:\folder1\d.txt"));
        List<FileInfo> SourceFiles = fr.fileList(@"U:\folder1");  //gets the FileInfo for each file in the folder
        List<FileInfo> DestFiles = fr.fileList(@"U:\folder2");


        //act
        List<FileInfo> result = flc.SourceNotInDest(FTPFiles, LocalFiles);

        //assert
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(result, expectedResult);
    }
```

Even though `result` and `expectedResult` have the same contents--both lists have one element with the same file path and same other properties--the test fails with the message:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1 occurrence(s)
of <U:\folder1\d.txt>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s).
```

`expectedResult` does have an occurrence of `U:\folder1\d.txt`, though.  I was thinking maybe the problem is that I'm comparing the memory addresses for two objects instead of the contents of those objects, but I thought the `AreEquivalent()` was comparing properties.  Is that not the case?

EDIT: Based on the advice about comparing properties instead of addresses, I used this Assert instead, which allowed the test to pass:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi1 in result)
    {
     Assert.IsNotNull(expectedResult.Find(fi2 => fi2.FullName == fi1.FullName));
    }
foreach (FileInfo fi1 in expectedResult)
    {
     Assert.IsNotNull(result.Find(fi2 => fi2.FullName == fi1.FullName));
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because `FileInfo` is a reference type and the default comparer just checks for the two elements' addresses to be equals. Since `FileInfo` is sealed, you can't derive from it and override the equality comparers. The best option, in my opinion, would be writing your own collection comparer method (since you can't pass an `IEqualityComparer` instance to `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`).

Answer (score 4):

The test is failing because your collections have different objects in them.  If you have 2 instances of the `FileInfo` class that refer to the same file, and you call `instanceA.Equals(instanceB)`, the result is `false`.

If you could change your code to use strings instead of `FileInfo`s, it would work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest 2 approaches which are better than your one in my opinion :)

1. Select 2 collections of file names and compare these collections:

   ```
   CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(
       result.Select(fi => fi.FullName).ToArray(),
       expectedResult.Select(fi => fi.FullName).ToArray()
   );
   // ToArray() is added just for better output when test fails.
   ```
2. Use user-defined comparer and compare `FileInfo` lists:

   ```
   Assert.That(
       result,
       Is
           .EquivalentTo(expectedResult)
           .Using((Comparison<FileInfo>)((fi1, fi2) => fi1.FullName.CompareTo(fi2.FullName)))
   );
   ```

Your current implementaion with two foreach loops won't fail in the following case:

```
result =
    u:\folder1\a.txt
    u:\folder1\a.txt

expectedResult =
    u:\folder1\a.txt
```

Yeah, it doesn't seem to be real case for files list, but generaly it is not a good idea to replace `AreEquivalent()`/`Is.EquivalentTo()` with two loops.