# Looking for the name of a C# syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I've been away from C# for a while and now that I'm trying to read some code, I'm having a hard time find the meaning of it:

```
var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8181");
server.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Open!");
        allSockets.Add(socket);
    };
    socket.OnClose = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Close!");
        allSockets.Remove(socket);
    };
    socket.OnMessage = message =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));
    };
});
```

What's the name for `socket => { .. }` syntax and where can I find some text on it? And in which version of C# is it introduced? Is the `= () => { .. }` the same?

Comment: It is a lambda expression, anonymous delegate.

Comment: You mean "anonymous method".

Comment: All I can say is that it's a really ugly syntax to read!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Lambda expression, why should I use this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in c# this syntax is called Lambda Expressions. They are available since C# 3.0

more about:

Microsoft's Programming Guide [explaining lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[C# Lambda expressions: Why should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)

and an [example](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-2) of programmersheaven.com

Answer (score 4):

It is a lambda expression, basically it is a shortcut for defining delegates, which are anonimous methods. It was introduced in C# 3 along with LINQ to make its use much simpler. Syntax is as follow:

```
parameters => body
```

Usually the compiler can infer in some way the type of the parameter, that's why you see only the names of the parameters.

Comment: Delegates are *references* to methods; they are not actually methods. A delegate can reference a normal method or an anonymous method. A lambda expression is an anonymous method, though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson lambdas are references as well, I just wanted to keep my answer simple

Comment: Er, not they aren't - they are methods, but you can create a delegate to store a reference to them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx