# Check for null value of model property inside partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a asp.net mvc 3 application and I've made several partial views each one responsible for rendering of specific logic. Inside one of my views I use properties which can be null, but I don't want to pass null to the `@Html.DisplayFor()` and write something more user friendly to the user to know that these fields are not missing, they just don't have nothing assigned to them yet.

So I try this :

```
<tr>        
            <td>   
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[0][0].FieldValue))
                {            
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model[0][0].FieldValue)
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model[1][0].FieldValue) 
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I don't have `else` clause because writing the `if` statement results in getting both `Model =>` in the `DisplayFor` marked with red and the following message :

> A local variable named 'Model' can not be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'Model' which is already
>   used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something.

Basically I think I understand what this error means however I don't know how to check for null properly in this situation.

Comment: can i see the code of this partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is caused by the redefinition of the Model variable. Try

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[0][0].FieldValue)
```

You might find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this) useful to understand the "=>" thingie.