# Some unclear C# features

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, syntax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have started learning MVC and I run into some unclear lines.
Here is the link for the tutorial: [The Tutorial Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

So the problem is with the part of **Strongly Typed Models and the @model Keyword**

 This is the first thing I did not understand:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{...}
```

**1.** The first line of this method, I didn't really understood what does the ?(question mark) symbolize and what does it mean ?

And the other thing is here:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
```

**2.**And for this line, my question is what is that  **=>**  used for ?

Thank You.

Comment: Those are not MVC specific, but C# language features. You need to look at [Nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) and [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this

Answer (score 2):

The question mark indicates that the [type is nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

The `=>` is part of a [lambda statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1) The ? on int? means it's a nullable int, i.e. an int cannot normally be null, but a nullable int can.

When you use it inside an Action parameter it is basically making the parameter optional.

2) The => is part of a lambda expression / statement which is not easily explained, see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx)

```
model => model.Title
```

Basically means with the model, use the Title attribute and pass the Title to the DisplayNameFor method.