# lambda expression function

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this code:

```
int pictureId=10;
string cacheKey = string.Format(ModelCacheEventConsumer.PICTURE_URL_MODEL_KEY, pictureId);
        return _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, () =>
        {
            var url = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(pictureId, showDefaultPicture: false);
            //little hack here. nulls aren't cacheable so set it to ""
            if (url == null)
                url = "";

            return url;
        });
```

What exactly this part of code means:"

```
() =>
{"
   var url =...."
```

Does it mean that function, which returns URL, is executed for every row from cache? What is then return type - list?

URL of documentation of this syntax?

Comment: What type is _cacheManager?

Comment: _cacheManager implements ICacheManager IDisposable interface, which has method Get defined as:
T Get<T>(string key);

Answer (score 4):

Second parameter to _cacheManager.Get() method is an anonymous method that captures pictureId and among other things.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

[C# Lambda expressions: Why should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/)

To figure out the returned type, try using var keyword and creating a local variable: instead of `return _cacheManager.Get()` write `var x = _cacheManager.Get()` followed by `return x`.  Then simply hover over the keyword var in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly this part of code means

It's just passing a method by parameter.

> Does it mean that function, which returns URL, is executed for every row from cache?

Only the content of the method `Get` of the object `_cacheManager` can answer this.

> What is then return type - list?

The return type is a **string**, since your variable `url` is a string.

Comment: Sorry, i mean what type is variable returned from Get method, like list of strings or array of strings..

Comment: @Simon its only possible to answer it looking inside the method Get or passing the mouse over the method (if you're using Visual Studio). The return type will be shown for you

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly this part of code means:

Well, lambda expression is a "shortcut" for delegate, and delegate is a reference to a callback function (in a very simple explanation). So this is a function which will be called inside your `Get` method of cache manager, which expects to have a `Func` delegate as a second param

> Does it mean that function, which returns URL, is executed for every row from cache?

I think it will executes for row which has a key value the same as the value of `cacheKey` variable.. So, only one time (if keys are unique)

> What is then return type - list?

The return type is string, because if result of `GetPictureUrl` is null it returns empty string. And calling this method is expecting to have a string in a result also