# How to count number of occurences of every word in a sentence in c#?

Tags: c#, string, count, cpu-word

Ok, so I started with this:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] strSeparator = new string[] { " " };
```

But I don't know how to count the occurances.
My question is, which is the easiest method? I found something like this:

```
var result  = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .GroupBy(r => r)
            .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Word = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Count()
                });
```

But I don't understand who is 'r' or 'grp' and how I declare them. It'll be helpful some advice and examples.

Comment: This is really just a lack of understanding of what a lambda expression is in C#, I suggest you go read up on them.

Comment: [Your one stop shop for answers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AlexK. Tempted to hammer this closed for that, but I wonder if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-why-should-i-use-them) is better?

Comment: @claud I've closed this as a duplicate showing you how to count words, but your real questions are about lambdas, so see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-why-should-i-use-them) for that info.

Comment: @DavidG Ok, I will inform. Thanks for answers