# Is it possible to use variable name and boolean value in method parameters?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a few methods that have similar structure to each other. The only difference is the variable that is begin tested and which boolean condition is required.

```
public void OP_BCS(sbyte b)
{
    cv.PC += 2;

    if (cv._C == true)
    {
        cv.PC += (ushort)b;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the above code to something similar to what I have below (syntax might be incorrect, but should work in explaining what I mean)

```
public void OP_Branch(variable name, boolean condition, sbyte b)
{
    cv.PC += 2;

    if (variable == condition)
    {
        cv.PC += (ushort)b;
    }
}
```

I'd be able to make all the different combinations I need simply by giving the method a few extra parameters.

Comment: Consider making a `Dictionary<string, byte>`.

Comment: @SusiKette - your code is not very readable - consider using m ore meaningful names?

Comment: Perhaps [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-why-should-i-use-them) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take a `bool` as a parameter?

```
public void OP_Branch(bool condition, sbyte b)
{
    cv.PC += 2;

    if (condition)
    {
        cv.PC += (ushort)b;
    }
}
```

Then when you call it, you do the comparison in the method call:

```
OP_Branch(variable == condition, b);
```